# How to store Switch value and date in swift 4

Tags: swift, codable

I am making a ToDo List application.  I want to be able to save my switch choice and the date that the switch was turned on to show that the item on the list has been completed.  I have the array stored but I cannot figure out how to save the date and switch.  I am only going to be showing the first item for now.

Here is my ToDoListManager:

```
import Foundation

class ToDoListManager {

private static let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
private static let listKey = "ToDoListKey"

var toDoItems: [ToDoItem]
var completedSwitch: Bool

init() {
    self.toDoItems = ToDoListManager.retrieve() ?? [ToDoItem]()
 //* I don't know how to initialize my completedSwitch
 /*   self.completedSwitch =
 *//
}

func getItems() -> [ToDoItem] {
    return self.toDoItems
}

func numberItems() -> Int {
    return self.toDoItems.count
}

func addItem(item: ToDoItem) {
    self.toDoItems.append(item)
    ToDoListManager.store(items: self.toDoItems)
}

func removeItem(index: Int) {
    self.toDoItems.remove(at: index)
}

func getFirstItem() -> ToDoItem? {
    return self.toDoItems.first
}
func getDateCompleted() -> Bool {
    if completedSwitch == true{
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private class func store(items:[ToDoItem]) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
        userDefaults.set(encoded, forKey: listKey)
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

private class func retrieve() -> [ToDoItem]? {
    if let items = userDefaults.value(forKey: listKey) as? Data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let objectsDecoded = try? decoder.decode(Array.self, from: 
items) as [ToDoItem] {
            return objectsDecoded
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

My VC:

```
import UIKit
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateAddedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var completed: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var dateCompletedLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func completedSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
        dateCompletedLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        dateCompletedLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
var toDoItem: ToDoItem! {
    didSet(newItem) {
        self.refreshUI()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    refreshUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func refreshUI() {

    if(toDoItem == nil) {
        return
    }
    descriptionLabel?.text = toDoItem.itemDescription
    completed.setOn(toDoItem.completed, animated: true)
    dateAddedLabel?.text = toDoItem.getDateAdded()
    dateCompletedLabel?.text = toDoItem.getDateCompleted()
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe create an @IBAction for your switch and put the code to save Date() and its value ?

Comment: When I add the s@IBAction, I get an error saying Value of type Bool has no member .isOn

Comment: You are creating a variable Bool... you must use a UISwitch type `@IBAction func completedSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) { sender.isOn }`

Comment: Another thing, to set the UISwitch you must use `completedSwitch.setOn(true, animated: false)`

Comment: I changed it to look like this:   @IBAction func completedSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {sender.isOn}
 and the error I get is "Expression resolves to an unused l-value"

Comment: friend, `sender.isOn` is your bool value indicating the switch position, you must use it to store it in your model. I will post an answer but I'm having really bad time trying to understand you

Comment: Sorry, I am learning.

Comment: This is not a problem, everybody pass through it. Just try to understand swift's structure and its types. When you post a question, try to be extremely clear then we can help you better. Hope my answer gives you a good north and you achieve your goal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160038/discussion-between-jenn-oliver-and-gijow).

Answer (score -1):

This is just an example how switch works.

You can also get its value by `completedSwitch.isOn` anywhere in your VC.

```
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateAddedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var completedSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func completedSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if sender.isOn {
        ///// do your stuffs if completed
    }
    else {
        ///// do your stuffs if NOT completed
    }
}

var toDoItem: ToDoItem! {
    didSet(newItem) {
        self.refreshUI()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    refreshUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func refreshUI() {

    if(toDoItem == nil) {
        return
    }
    descriptionLabel?.text = toDoItem.itemDescription
    completedSwitch?.setOn(toDoItem.completed, animated: true)
    dateAddedLabel?.text = toDoItem.getDateAdded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for down voting. Thats why I won't answer any newbies questions anymore